# How to make a POST request in twitter without header

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to create a twitter POST request without having the Oauth header 
My request will be like

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?oauth_signature=IeeuNHBH4bLhwy8w42Z0qbpXvFI%3D&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=ec2397446398196ff26b1c17a23cfdb6&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=gGrr4khdilkzano8gYxK4Q&oauth_token=146439820-n07FzSB78bDWEUzPPP9WZnwdnwW917FyJi1gwKWM&oauth_timestamp=1341388264'--data 'status=hello+world'
```

Kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do.

Those are "`GET` params".

Try using the `-d` flag with CURL to send `POST` body parameters. (It's the same flag as the `--data` param you're using elsewhere.)